# IOS App suspended automatically

Tags: ios

I have a problem in my release iOS app...

When i use my app and through all of feature (Like to another view in my app etc) in my app and then i click home button in ios to switch in to another app then i switch back to my app. My latest state (View) still exist. However, when i switch in to another app for a while, my app restarting from splash screen.
Another problem when i am trying to detect the problem in my ios simulator, the problem i have in the release app could not appear in my ios simulator.

Any people here could give me a solution to fix my problem ?

If the problem i have in memory usage, how many memory usage can be tolerated by IOS system ? and how can i know from ios simulator that memory usage is greater than the limit ?

additional info : my iOS app is based on objective-c and mixing with swift code. I use XCODE 8 and my app not using background service like download video, music, and etc. However, i use nsurlsession to fetch data from server and using data from server to load image from server. I use sdwebimage to handle image.
I hope this picture can give another insight about my app. This picture i take when my position in home of IOS, not in my app

[image]

Comment: What problem are you referring to? The behavior you see is perfectly normal.

Comment: Maybe the OTHER app that you switched to is requesting more memory, so the system stop your app to get enough memory for it

Answer (score 0):

It probably *is* memory usage. The job of the WatchDog process is to look for suspended memory hogs and kill them. You appear to be one.

You can readily see in Xcode how much memory you were using when you went into the background. How much was it? If it's a lot, don't do that. It's your job to release as much memory as you can when you go into the background, for this very reason.

However, your app can *never* hope to live forever — sooner or later, it *will* be killed in the background — so another responsibility you have is to save its state and, if you are launched from scratch, restore that state. That's just how iOS works.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, in my edited post, i have been posted the picture that informing about memory usage when i went into the background. is it normal for my app ?

Comment: Sure, that doesn't look at all extreme. Not at all. Either you are getting crowded out by other apps, or there is something you do _in_ the background that causes an issue. You can readily use Instruments to get a better picture of what's happening.